# switch method in java

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm trying to use the switch method to count the number of vowels and number of consonants in a string.
There is alot online for this problem but I must make sure characters like (!,$,&), numbers and spaces are not included as a consonants.

I have this atm.

```
  switch (ch) {
    case 'a':
    case 'e':
    case 'i':
    case 'o':
    case 'u':
      vowelCount ++; 
      break;
    default:
      consonantCount ++;
      break;
  }
```

How could I change the default to a specific case that only allows characters between a and z?

Answer (score 1):

> How could I change the default to a specific case that only allows characters between a and z?

The `default` case matches everything that has not be matched by other cases, and you can't change that.  Non-default cases only match a single *compile time* constant, and you can't change that either.

So the closest you can come with a `switch` statement will be to use an `if` statement within the `default` case.

```
  switch (ch) {
  case 'a': case 'e': case 'i': case 'o': case 'u':
      vowelCount++; 
      break;
  default:
      if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') {
          consonantCount++;
      }
      break;
  }
```

---

As @Oliver points out in his Answer, there are other (arguably better) ways to write the above without using a `switch` statement.  But I disagree with his characterization of `if` in `default` as "bad practice".

To my mind, the two most important things when talking about code quality are:

- The code should be **correct** in the sense that it does what it is supposed to do.
- The code should be sufficiently **readable** to whoever will need to read and maintain the code.

<sup>(I think we can all agree that these are *necessary* (if not *sufficient*) for good code, but I acknowledge that I have simplified this, for the sake of argument.)</sup>

However, reasoning that is based on "how specific constructs are intended to be used" is (IMO) based on two false assumptions:

- An assumption that the designers of Java did actually intend this ... absent any documentary evidence of their intention.
- An assumption that common usage patterns in Java cannot (or should not) evolve beyond the designers' original intentions.

For these reasons, I disagree with Oliver's blanket assertion that `if` statements in a `default` are "bad practice".  It depends on correctness and readability / maintainability of the code *in context*.

Answer (score 0):

A `switch` statement is not going to solve your problem nicely.

Personally, I consider it bad practice to nest an `if` statement inside the `default` case of a `switch` statement and is a sign that your pattern may need tweaking. For example

```
if(a == b || a == c || a == d)
```

could be written as

```
switch(a) {
  case b:
  case c:
  case d:
    // Code.
    break;
}
```

`Switch` and `if` statements serve different purposes. If you need to check a condition on the variable you are switching in your `default` case, then you probably should use an if `statement` or add more `case`s.

I suggest the following:

```
if(ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u') {
  vowelCount++;
} else if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') { // If the character code is between 'a' and 'z', inclusive.
  consonantCount++;
}
```

Comment: *"It is considered bad practice to nest an if statement inside the default case of a switch statement ..."* - By who?  Please provide a reference for this.  (Or just say that >>you<< consider it to be bad practice without implying that your opinion represents a general consensus.)

Comment: I updated my answer. I would consider it bad practice because it breaks the very idea of a `switch` statement. For example, `if(a == b || a == c || a == d)` could be written as `switch(a) { case b: case c: case d: break; }`. `Switch` and `if` statements serve different purposes. If you need to check a condition on the variable you are _switching_ in your `default` case, then you probably should use an `if` statement or add more cases.

Comment: Put that into your answer :-)

Comment: I updated it per my last comment. Please refresh your page. I am sorry for the poor wording on my part.

Comment: *"Switch and if statements serve different purposes. If you need to check a condition on the variable you are switching in your default case, then you probably should use an if statement or add more cases. "*  - Put >>that<< into your answer.  If you are going tell the reader that (you think) that this is bad practice, then your answer should clearly justify that statement.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Updated. By the way, I absolutely love your Q&A posts! I would imagine they are very helpful to new developers.

Answer (score 0):

This all seems a lot cleaner if you ditch your switch.

```
private static final String VOWELS = "aeiou";

public void count(String in) {
    int vowel = 0, consonant = 0;
    for (char c : in.toCharArray()) {
        if (VOWELS(c) > -1) vowel++;
        else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') consonant++;
    }
    System.out.printf("Vowels: %d Consonants: %d\n", vowel, consonant);
}
```